# View Full Site for Responsive Web Design

Tags: php, jquery

I using code change meta viewport

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {    

    var answer = confirm('Would you like to switch to the mobile version of kk');
    if (!sessionStorage.alreadyClicked) {
        if (answer)
        {
          console.log('yes');     
        }
        else
        {
          console.log('cancel');
           viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
           viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0');   
           //window.location = window.location.origin;  
        }
    }
}
```

How to retain meta viewport not be changed after page reload?

Answer (score 0):

Call this javascript function at onload time

```
<body onload="getDevicezType();">
```